# My car only overheats when radiator cap is on. FIXED

Tags: subaru, overheating, radiator

FIXED: I came back to a day later, needed 1/4 gallon more coolant and burped for 10 minutes and now it's fine. There might still be a leak in the radiator/cap/hose, but atm it's fixed.

Does that point to a specific problem? Can I drive a few miles without cap on?

00 subaru outback. Started overheating while driving. There was coolant everywhere, it looked like the resovoir cap got loose and it spit it everywhere.

Radiator was pretty empty, filled it up with coolant. Rev'd engine with cap off and it didn't overheat after minutes of reving. As soon as cap goes on, it overheats.

I know I need to buy a pressure kit for specific anwers, just curious if the cap off points to a specific problem.

Comment: If you jack your car up whilst letting it run for a bit the cooling system wil release more air bubbles. I know you have fixed it now but for the future.

Comment: As you don't need to get under the car, parking on an incline will work just as well for this. (Pointed uphill for most cars, but the key thing is to get the radiator cap opening elevated higher than the engine, so bubbles will rise to the high point)

Comment: If you found a fix, place that as an answer and don't edit it into your question, if you would please.